# How to read a NSDate in from a string?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have strings with dates, and want to parse these into NSDate objects. Is there a way to do that? I've looked at NSDate and NSScanner, and haven't seen anything that would read it in from a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cocoa sdk, it's usually: If you want a date and have a string, look in the "Date" class for a create method that accepts a string.

> [[NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString%3A) dateFromString:myString]
>
> dateFromString:
>
> Returns a date representation of a
>   given string interpreted using the
>   receiver’s current settings.
>
> (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string

So if you want a string and have a date, you look for an NSString Static function called stringFromDate (i'm guessing it exists but didn't look it up).  I will concede that NSDateFormatter doesn't strike me as the first place i'd look for this function though.

Comment: Didn't even think about a Formatter, since that sounds like something that prints out something nice. But good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Try [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:)