# How do I convert from NSString to NSDate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

how to convert from NSString to NSDate
?

it must be in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss this format when it converts from NSString to NSDate format

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348965/how-to-read-a-nsdate-in-from-a-string

Answer (score 11):

Use NSDateFormatter's dateFromString:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20100212";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 0):

For further ref. Check out:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Made an **NSString extension** for that.

```
// Simple as this.   
date = dateString.dateValue;
```

Thanks to [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it recognizes a whole lot of format.

```
// Tested in GMT+1 (Hungary).
@"2014-01-16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014.01.16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014/01/16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014 Jan 16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014 Jan 16th" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"20140116" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01-16-2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01.16.2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01/16/2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"16 January 2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01-16-2014 17:05:05" dateValue is <2014-01-16 16:05:05 +0000>
@"01-16-2014 T 17:05:05 UTC" dateValue is <2014-01-16 17:05:05 +0000>
@"17:05, 1 January 2014 (UTC)" dateValue is <2014-01-01 16:05:00 +0000>
```

Part of [eppz!kit](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit), grab the category [NSString+EPPZKit.h](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/NSString%2BEPPZKit.h) from GitHub.