# How to get date from a string (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, string, nsdateformatter, date-format

```
I need to convert this string in to the date:

    02-09-2011 20:54:18

I am trying the `dateFromString` method but every time it is returning (null), what NSDateFormatter should I use?, I have tried
`[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]` and `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]`.


Here is my code:
NSString *finalDate = @"02-09-2011 20:54:18";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *dateString = [formatter dateFromString:finalDate];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);


Thanks.
```

Comment: For a while I thought this was some kind of computer science question about something called a "Daye form"... you disappointed me :(

Comment: No one can make Daye form string.

Comment: Why you set date format two times. give code for solution you definitely make some silly mistake

Comment: why not you give some code where you get problem.And also make difference for different cases as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert a NSString containing a date to a NSDate using the NSDateFormatter with the following code:

```
// Your date as a string
NSString *finalDate = @"02-09-2011 20:54:18";

// Prepare an NSDateFormatter to convert to and from the string representation
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// ...using a date format corresponding to your date
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

// Parse the string representation of the date
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finalDate];

// Write the date back out using the same format
NSLog(@"Month %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: THANKS A TON,  Ur answer is exactly i was looking for, i was expecting thee error in the date Format, i searched a lot for the correct date format but didn't get thanks once again :-)

Comment: Converting a string to Date object returns the date in GMT(Greenwich Mean Time).

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's easier to search than it is to ask?

[How do I convert from NSString to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251777/how-do-i-convert-from-nsstring-to-nsdate)